# AngularJS - $routeProvider and resolve not auto updating the view

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express

I am having trouble getting resolve in  $routeProvider to automatically update the view.

I am trying to convert an example (chapter 22) in Adam Freeman's Pro Angular book from Deployd to Express-Mongo. A possible hint is that the automatic refresh works using a local version of Deployd. When I switched to local Express and Mongo backend (after making the id to _id changes), the automatic view update no longer works.

When using Express-Mongo, I have to manually execute  $route.reload() function to get show the updated changes from the database. I am new to angular so any hints are appreciated.

This heavy handed Delete works:

```
$scope.deleteProduct = function (product) {
    product.$delete();
    $route.reload();
    $location.path("/list");
}
```

The below version Doesn't work. I was under the (probably mistaken) impression that the 'resolve' property in $routeProvider updates the view when the data is returned. With the below code, I get a Type Error: Undefined is not a function

```
 $scope.deleteProduct = function (product) {
        product.$delete().then(function () {
            $scope.data.products.splice($scope.data.products.indexOf(product), 1);
});
        $location.path("/list");
}
```

Console Log Errors

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js:530:25
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:302:11)
    at angular.module.factory.Resource.(anonymous function).$http.then.value.$resolved (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js:529:17)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10905:81)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10905:81)
    at http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10991:26
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11906:28)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11734:31)
    at Scope.ng.config.$provide.decorator.$delegate.__proto__.$digest (<anonymous>:844:31) angular.js:9383
```

Below is the code for the module

```
 angular.module("exampleApp", ["ngResource", "ngRoute"])
        .constant("baseUrl", "http://localhost:8080/api/products/")          
        .factory("productsResource", function ($resource, baseUrl) {
        return $resource(baseUrl + ":id", { id: "@_id" },
          {
              create: { method: "POST" , isArray: true },
              save: { method: "PUT", isArray: true },
              delete: {method: "DELETE", isArray: true},
              update: {method: "PUT", isArray: true},
              query: {method: "GET", isArray: true}
          })
})

        .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
                ...
                $routeProvider.otherwise({
                templateUrl: "/views/tableView.html",
                controller: "tableCtrl",
                resolve: {
                    data: function (productsResource) {
                        return productsResource.query();
                    }
                }
            });
        })

.controller("defaultCtrl", function ($scope, $location, productsResource, $route) {
        $scope.data = {};
        $scope.deleteProduct = function (product) {
                  product.$delete().then(function(products) {
                      //Success
                      console.log("Success");  //Don't Get Here
                      $scope.data.products.splice($scope.data.products.indexOf(product), 1);

                  }, function(errResponse) {
                      //Failure (Code Produces a Type Error: Undefined is not a function)
                      console.log("Error: " +  errResponse); 
                  });

                  $location.path("/list");
              }
})
```

The Table View Controller that is bound to the $routeProvider.otherwise

```
.controller("tableCtrl", function ($scope, $location, $route, data) {
    $scope.data.products = data;
    $scope.refreshProducts = function () {
        $route.reload();
} })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should redirect when the delete is complete:

```
$scope.deleteProduct = function (product) {
    product.$delete().then(function () {
        $scope.data.products.splice($scope.data.products.indexOf(product), 1);
        $location.path("/list");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such  quick response :) With the above code, I'm still getting the same 'TypeError: undefined is not a function error'
 at http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js:530:25
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:302:11)
    at angular.module.factory.Resource.(anonymous function).$http.then.value.$resolved (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js:529:17)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback .....

Comment: Remove the line: `$scope.data.products.splice($scope.data.products.indexOf(product), 1);` and check result

Comment: I removed the line above and am still getting the same 'TypeError: undefined is not a function error'

Answer (score 0):

You have missed } at the and of line with text:

```
delete: {method: "DELETE", isArray: true
```

Comment: I fixed the dumb typo:  delete: {method: "DELETE", isArray: true},
Sadly, I'm getting the same TypeError: undefined is not a function.

Comment: And one more type at the end of line: query: {method: "GET", isArray: true}} (double }})

Comment: .factory("productsResource", function ($resource, baseUrl) {
        return $resource(baseUrl + ":id", { id: "@_id" },
              {
                  create: { method: "POST" , isArray: true },
                  save: { method: "PUT", isArray: true },
                  delete: {method: "DELETE", isArray: true},
                  update: {method: "PUT", isArray: true},
                  query: {method: "GET", isArray: true}
              }


        )

Comment: After this changes - what kind of error do you have?

Comment: Sorry about the delay. I'm still getting the same error: TypeError: undefined is not a function. I also edited the originalcode above to reflect the change

Comment: what value is returned by `product.$delete()`?

Comment: I'm getting TypeError Undefined is not a function

Comment: `$scope.deleteProduct = function (product) {
`product.$delete().then(function () {
`//Success
`console.log("Was a Success!");                   ` `$scope.data.products.splice($scope.data.products.indexOf(product), 1);
`}, function(errResponse) {
`//Failure
`console.log("Error Message: "+  errResponse);
`});
`$location.path("/list");
`}

Comment: just console.log(product.$delete) or console.log(typeof product.$delete)

Comment: function (params, success, error) {
          if (isFunction(params)) {
            error = success; success = params; params = {};
          }
          var result = Resource[name].call(this, params, this, success, error);
          return result.$promise || result;
        }